# Loading reference output of an ADC

Tags: adc, voltage-reference

My ADC (LTC2323, 16 bit, 5MSps, http://www.linear.com/product/LTC2323-16) has an internal reference (4.096V) which is provided at output pins `REFINTx`. Now I need (roughly) half of this reference voltage for the ADC driver. The reference output is **buffered** and referred to another pin `REFRTNx` - to my understanding for proper decoupling but otherwise "close enough" to GND. The datasheet does not explicitely confirm or deny that I can load this pin externally but it somewhat suggests I can. What I found in the datasheet:

**REFOUT1 (Pin 12)**: *Reference Buffer 1 Output. An onboard buffer nominally outputs 4.096V to this pin. This pin is referred to `REFRTN1` and should be decoupled closely to the pin (no vias) with a 0.1µF (X7R, 0402 size) capacitor and a 10μF (X5R, 0805 size) ceramic capacitor in parallel. [...]*

**REFRTN1 (Pin 11)**: *Reference Buffer 1 Output Return. Bypass `REFRTN1` to REFOUT1. Do not tie the REFRTN1 pin to the ground plane.*

Under "Internal Reference Characteristics" it is stated: *REFOUT1,2 Output Impedance: 0.25 Ohm.*

Furthermore:

**Internal Reference:** *The LTC2323-16 has an on-chip, low noise, low drift (20ppm/°C max), temperature compensated bandgap reference. It is **internally buffered** and is **available at `REFOUT1,2`** (Pins 12, 26). The reference buffer gains the internal reference voltage to 4.096V for supply voltages VDD = 5V and to 2.048V for VDD = 3.3V. Bypass `REFOUT1,2` to `REFRTN1,2` with the parallel combination of a 0.1µF (X7R, 0402 size) capacitor and a 10μF (X5R,
0805 size) ceramic capacitor to compensate the reference buffer and minimize noise. The 0.1µF capacitor should be as close as possible to the LTC2323-14 package to minimize wiring inductance. Tie the REFINT pin to V DD to
enable the internal reference buffer.*

Can I load this pin externally and if yes - how much? Can I attach a resistive divider of, say 10k, to get 1/2 of the ref voltage? Or at least the input of a simple op-amp follower?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to load the reference output. I wouldn't load it with much less than \$500\Omega\$, but you should be fine with something above that.

Comment: That sounds great! Would you mind adding how you arrived at this conclusion? Either experience or calculations/datasheet and if so - how?

Comment: The data sheet lists the maximum pin current at 10mA, at 4.096V a 500Ohm load draws 8mA.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Isink" symbol in the datasheet (on page 4)? This is for the digital I/O pins. I did unfortunately not find more specs on the reference pin other than 0.25 Ohm output impedance (page 3 bottom)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to, as that's the best figure they've got.